# Script that runs itself every now and then

Tags: powershell

I work in marine systems institute. We have a buoy that sends information about the sea every few hours to a central computer in the institute. It drops it as a .txt file in a certain folder. It would be really great if I could make a script that looks into that folder every 3 hours and checks if there are any new files. If there is a new file, it should upload it to an ftp.

I have no idea where to start. Are there any suggestions what language, where to look, what to search etc.

The computer is running 24/7 and the script can easily be an executable that is active all the time. The script doesn't have to restart itself every time, it can be up and running 24/7 also.

Thanks in advance

EDIT1: My op.sys is windows

Comment: Would you add details of what platform/technology you are working with?

Comment: What is your operating system? Is it Windows? or Linux?

Comment: Oh sorry! My op.sys is windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your platform is Windows, I suggest Windows Forms Application. An IDE is available, Visual Studio - it is easy to use and has everything you need for your application. You basically need a timer object that will execute a function (checking the file) in a certain interval. 3 hours is long enough, you can even check it every 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotKey can be learned by anyone in a day, and is powerful enough to do what you describe.

A program written in a real language could do exactly what you like with full customization, robustness, portability, and maintainability, but will take quite a bit longer to make.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ftp client such as [smartftp](http://www.smartftp.com) which can watch the folder where the files are created, and automatically upload them.

Comment: I think that it wouldn't work for me, because after checking it has to verify, that the information in that file is valid and only then send it to the ftp.

Comment: If you need to perform custom logic, you definitely need some sort of custom code. 

You could either write for example a simple .net program as suggested with the FSWatcher class.

Comment: Another option that might seem overkill (but should be quite simple) is actually to use an ESB such as Mule. In there you can configure "endpoints" such as watched folders, email folders and ftp servers, and custom logic to apply to messages sent between these endpoints. In that case you would not have to code the plumbing (watching folders, uploading etc.), only the validation code. http://www.mulesoft.com It would take some tinkering to get up and running, but it would be very robust and extensible.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little over your head if you never done any programming(Forgive me if you have).

A good solution is to use FileSystemWatcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx. Then create a windows service to run it.

But again that takes some experience implementing.